# Error in the PyCharm Python terminal, indicates the sign

Tags: python, pycharm, telegram

After updating PyCharm, an error started popping up in the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\kant\Desktop\Шаблон TelegramBot> python main.py
Сбой выполнения программы python.exe: Системе не удается найти указанный путьстрока:1 знак:1
+ python main.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
строка:1 знак:1
+ python main.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Pops up after python main.py

I can't figure out what the problem is

Comment: I don't read that language, but it looks like the command `python` was not found.

Comment: That's right, it looks like the problem was in python 3.11 after reinstalling everything is fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Mr.Bait. Be sure to be more specific about your question requests. The terminal and Pycharm are two different realms in some degree. Not necessarily one interferes with the other. Although they might. Another point here is, since you are in an English speaking community, help us out in translating the error messages. Translators sometimes fail us. I am up voting this, because my comment and John's can help Stack newcomers, and programming novices to take a better route asking questions in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шt looks like the problem was in python 3.11 after reinstalling everything is fine

Comment: You probably did not have Python in the path. Set up as an environment variable for accessibility from the terminal, as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)